# Change element CSS when a div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to remove a CSS line of code when a certain `div` is reached?

Please note:

- I need the CSS class that contains this line of code
- The `div` is reached by clicking a link in the page header so I think `mouseenter()` event is not enough.

My Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //firing the event to change CSS when reaching #resume 

    $('#resume').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#resume').class('education').css('border-bottom','');
    });
});
```

```css
.education, .work {
   margin-bottom: 48px;
   padding-bottom: 24px;
   //border-bottom: 1px solid #E8E8E8;
}
```

```html
   <section id="resume">
      <!-- Education -->
      <div class="row education">

         <div class="three columns header-col">
            <h1><span>Education</span></h1>
         </div>

         
         <div class="education work">
         </div> <!-- main-col end -->

      </div> <!-- End Education -->
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. There's no `.class()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is on assumption that the class is already set on the element, and you just want to remove the border-bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //firing the event to change CSS when reaching #resume 

    $('#resume').mouseenter(function(){
            //You can use 'this' as it is in the context of this element
            //It will look inside the context element, then find all elements with class "education" and set the border-bottom to none.
            $(this).find(".education").css({'border-bottom' : 'none'});

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When reaching `#resume`, you mean by scrolling? Then you need to use `$(window).scroll()` function / event:

```
$(function () {
  // To change on scroll and reach `#resume`.
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $("#resume").offset().top)
      $('#resume').addClass('education').css('border-bottom', '0');
  });
  // To change when hovering.
  $('#resume').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass('education').css('border-bottom', '0');
    $(this).find(".education").css('border-bottom', '0');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

just use the class name

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // firing the event to change CSS when reaching #resume 
    $('#resume').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.education').css('border-bottom','');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove your class and add a new class containing the right css.

```
$(this).removeClass('someClass');
$(this).addClass('someClass');
```

Otherwise you could do something like this:

```
$(this).css({'border-bottom' : ''});
```

You can use 'this' when it is in the context of the element

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var Bind = function(elem, event, func) {
      elem[window.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent'](window.addEventListener ? event : 'on' + event, func, false);
    },
    scrollPos = function() {
      var doc = document.documentElement;
      return {
        'left': (window.pageXOffset || doc.scrollLeft) - (doc.clientLeft || 0),
        'top': (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0)
      };
    },
    tgtOffset = document.getElementById('tgt').offsetTop,
    scrolled = false,
    spotted = function() {
      var dist = tgtOffset - scrollPos().top,
        adj = window.innerHeight > (480 / 2) ? window.innerHeight : 100;
      return dist > -100 && dist < adj;
    },
    inView = null;
  var res = document.getElementById('resume');

  Bind(window, 'scroll', function(event) {
    clearTimeout(inView);
    if (!scrolled && spotted()) {
      inView = setTimeout(function() {
        res.classList.add('education');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.education,
.work {
  margin-bottom: 48px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  // border-bottom: 1px solid #E8E8E8;

}
```

```html
<section id="resume">
  <!-- Education -->
  <div class="row education">

    <div class="three columns header-col">
      <h1><span>Education</span></h1>
    </div>


    <div class="education work">
    </div>
    <!-- main-col end -->

  </div>
  <!-- End Education -->
```